# Patch update operation for json document in MarkLogic using Java API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I am trying to update the property value of **JSON** document which of datatype **date** I am using the following function,

```
DocumentPatchBuilder.replaceValue("date",new Date());
```

When this patch is applied the date property value is getting stored as **String**. Is there any way or any other function so that I can update the date value using DocumentPatchBuilder?

Answer (score 4):

A date is not a native JSON data type. What else would you expect it to be represented as besides a string?

If you want to store a date or dateTime in a JSON document and have it be indexable as such by MarkLogic, you need to use one of the date or time formats recognized by XML Schema. See this topic for details:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/json#id_64992